# tessaract ocr on url image gives me 100% error file

Tags: ocr, tesseract

When I run tessaract on a PNG image containing only urls, it gives me a 100% error output

like:

```
Jcâa\râcL7mpnmeVr
Jevuusdwvmceranr
pmmyhemnï¬r
nnnnnysaaan
ï¬mï¬asmunï¬r
```

Is there a way to get a better result : image is clean and readable.

I tried with GOCR, and result is like 70% good (which is still not good enough for me)

Any chance to use a linux command line OCR  to get better results ?

Comment: Hi Yarek, strange behaviour... 
I run TesserAct 3.02 on a command line, and the url of this stackoverflow is my input. Both Tahoma and Times New Roman are tested.

This is my 'test' output.
TAHOMA

 
http://stackoverflow .com/questions/26829265/tessa ract-ocr-on -url -image-gives-me-100-error-ﬁ Ie


www.google.com


Times New Roman

http ://sta ckoverflow. com/questi ons/268 2926 5/tessaract-ocr-on-url-image-gives-1ne-1 0 0-en'or-ﬂ le